# Localized.strings not accessed

Tags: ios, storyboard, localizable.strings

I have two storyboards, one for the iPhone 5 and one for the iPhone 4.  The same code supports both.  I have have NSLocalizedStrings all through the code.  When I run the code on an G4 device, the strings are displayed just fine.  But when I run the exact same code with the G5 storyboard, the most recent strings come through as their IDs, not their equivalent strings.  Does anyone have suggestions on what may be going on?  Do storyboards affect search paths for localized strings?  If so where?  I've seen bugs due to the speed differences of the G4 and G5 devices but this seems the opposite of the previous patterns.

I figured it out looking at someother problems.  The app has to be deleted from the device and/or a new name assigned to it.